# Magento - Auto set radio button “Thumbnails” to 1st uploaded images?

Tags: image, magento, thumbnails

I need realised simple feature.
Then user add images to new products - first uploaded images must be selected as Thumbnail, Small Image, Base Image. 
See this ([image](http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/472/0585014229.jpg))
I add images from Magento Admin - all is standard and usual.

I hope it will be possible?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_media_gallery AS mg, 
catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value AS mgv, 
catalog_product_entity_varchar AS ev 
SET ev.value = mg.value 
WHERE  mg.value_id = mgv.value_id AND mg.entity_id = ev.entity_id AND ev.attribute_id 
IN (85, 86, 87) AND mgv.position = 1;
```

The `ev.attribute_id` numbers might be different for different databases. Mine are these ones, but most I have seen on the Internet are `74, 75, 76` or `70, 71, 72`, so be sure to check for yourself the correct ones for your case.

Comment: please edit your answer and format to code to make it readable